# excel vba copy paste cells without user noticing

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have a macro which copies and pastes a lot of cells in a different worksheet. This works fine, my question is:

**Is it possible to make the whole macro run in the background?**

As the macro will be used by inexperienced excel-users, I dont want them to see the macro jumping around and copying loads of data which makes the screen go crazy.

Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: A quick internet search would give you the answer, but for your convenience, to turn off screen updating: Application.ScreenUpdating = False and to turn back on: Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Comment: My sub procedures don't go *'jumping around and copying loads of data which makes the screen go crazy'*. If your 'macros' do, read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/28700020).

Comment: If your macro is running and `jumping around`, I would throw up a modal form with text, something along the lines of: **Please wait, processing in progress...**. You don't want people updating a worksheet while its being updated anyway

Comment: I found this one of the best explanations online, it is a function I use in all my macros - https://analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/

Comment: @5202456 normally I don't have a problem googling stuff, but as english isn't my first language, explaining a problem to the search bar can sometimes prove quite difficult, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Jeeped I used Range("xy").copy and paste ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `application.screenupdating = false` at the start of the macro

then `Application.Screenupdating = true` at the end, and the screen won't jump around.

Also worth adding `Msgbox("The macro has finished!")`  or something similar at the end so that they know it has done its thing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your 'macro' looks like this.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=4
    Range("J16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=5
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=2
    Range("I19").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-72
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

It would be better if written like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("I19") = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("J16").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Learn more with [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/28700020).

Comment: Or `Worksheets("sheet1").Range("J16").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I19")` if you want to copy formatting, etc, too

Answer (score 1):

You have the following tools at hand to achieve your goals:

- `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` ' turn off screen updating

This will hide any screen updates until you turn it on again. If your application is jumping around with various `.Activate` etc. you may want to save the initial selection point before

- various event triggered Sub

To start something "in the background" you may initiate it

```
Workbook.Open
Workbook.SheetActivate, Workbook.SheetDeactivate
Worksheet.Activate, Worksheet.Deactivate
' etc.
```